# 506 Invalid MERCHANT_ID or ACCOUNT. Please contact the merchant Global payment HPP

Tags: global-payments-api

I am testing HPP payments and I follow the example code provided [here](https://developer.globalpay.com/ecommerce/hosted-payment-page#hpp) in Developer portal.
I have created an account on the portal and have found below information on my test app.

I always get These 2 errors.

506  Invalid MERCHANT_ID or ACCOUNT. Please contact the merchant.
508  Invalid data in MERCHANT_ID field. Please contact the merchant.

Merchant Id: MER_c4c0df11039c48a9b63701adeaa296c3

Below is my PHP code from the Server endpoint.

```
$config->merchantId = "MER_c4c0df11039c48a9b63701adeaa296c3";
$config->accountId = "internet";
$config->sharedSecret = "LYZIFACE9hHngwOy";
$config->serviceUrl = "https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay";
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: you have to apply for an e-commerce portal test account [here](https://realcontrol.realexpayments.com/) and use the assigned merchant id and secret you get once you are approved. That Merchant Id really is invalid.

The global payments SDK seems to send back the data in base64 format for example:

```
{
    "MERCHANT_ID": "TUVSXzRjNWQ0NWIxMThmMjQzMGU5ZDhhNmQ1ZGZiNWQ0YzM0",
    "ACCOUNT": "c2VjcmV0",
    "CHANNEL": "",
    "ORDER_ID": "TURVeU1qZGxPVEF0TXpRM1lpMDBZelkwTFdGaU1qTXRaV0l6TmpNNVlXWTNZV0Zp",
    "AMOUNT": "MTAwMw==",
    "CURRENCY": "VVNE",
    "TIMESTAMP": "MjAyMTAyMTUxOTI5NTQ=",
    "AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG": "MQ==",
    "COMMENT1": "",
    "CUST_NUM": "",
    "PAYER_REF": "",
    "PMT_REF": "",
    "PROD_ID": "",
    "SHIPPING_CODE": "NTAwMDE=",
    "SHIPPING_CO": "ODQw",
    "VAR_REF": "",
    "HPP_LANG": "",
    "MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL": "",
    "CARD_PAYMENT_BUTTON": "",
    "HPP_VERSION": "Mg==",
    "SHA1HASH": "ZDAzNjUzMjIzMWFkZDE0YzMyM2ZjNWQyYzY0Njc1NTJhODVlZTkwMw=="
}
```

You may want to decode the string on your client-side before passing it to the rxp-js handler:

```js
let json = JSON.parse(res.toString());
Object.keys(json).forEach(key => json[key] = atob(json[key]));

RealexHpp.setHppUrl("https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay");
// When using full page redirect your Response URL must be an absolute link
RealexHpp.redirect.init("realCheckoutButton","http://localhost:3000/responseUrl",json);
```

Comment: where to find accountId